# axios can get the data, the console output 'code' is undefined, how to solve this problem?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Problem Description:
The data obtained using axios was successful, but the obtained data did not successfully enter the warehouse. There is an array in the warehouse, and the content of the array is empty.
Vscode did not report an error, and then I tried to restart the server  and console still reported an error.

Relevant code:

1. Error code:`index.js?8626:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code') at Store.getCategoryList`

2.axios request code:

api/index.js file:

```
export const reqGetCategoryList = () => {
requests.get('/product/getBaseCategoryList')}
```

home/index.js file:

```
    import { reqGetCategoryList } from "@/api"

const state = {
    categoryList: []
}
const mutations = {
    CATEGORYLIST(state, categoryList) {
        state.categoryList = categoryList
    }
}
const actions = {
    async getCategoryList({ commit }) {
        let result = await reqGetCategoryList();
        if (result.code==200) {
            commit("CATEGORYLIST", result.data)
        }
    }
}
const getters = {}

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

What are you expecting results? What is the actual error message you see?

The repository content I am expecting is categoryList:Array[17]

The content of the warehouse after the error is categoryList:Array[0]

Comment: `code` does not exist in the response schema as per documentation: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema. Do you mean `result.status`?

Comment: @Terry    The data obtained by my axios code is an object, which contains code: 200, message: success, data (some arrays in it), so I use result.code in the code, the code here is in the interface data content.
I didn't get an error when I did the project last time, so I shouldn't have used the wrong code, this time it's weird

Comment: Sounds like `code` is in the response from your server. If that's the case, shouldn't it be `result.data.code`?

Comment: @Terry  Here is the data returned by my code: {code: 200 data: [{,…}, {categoryChild: [{,…},…]] message: "success"}      The data and code here are side by side, I also tried your method, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @beginnerZ It's not a "method", `result.data.code` is the way it's supposed to work. Then data array should be `result.data.data`

Comment: @Terry and Estus Flask
Thank you for your enthusiastic replies, I have found the reason for the problem: I did not add return before "requests.get" in my api/index.js file, this part is an arrow function, if I use {}, then it must be Add return, if the arrow function body has only one sentence and I did not use {}, then return can be omitted